# Does NSSet use hash to define uniqueness?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsset

I've been working under the assumption that NSSet used hash to look up potential matches, and then called isEqual on each of those to check for real collisions, but I realized that I can't find any evidence to back this up.

The reason I bring it up is the existence of the "member:" method in NSSet.  Why does the documentation for member: go out of its way to specify that isEqual: is used to find your object when nothing else in NSSet does?  Does containsObject: only use the hash or something?

Can anyone confirm this behavior?  And ideally, reference documentation on it?

Answer (score 20):

I would suggest reading [Collections Programming Topics](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/Collections/Collections.html), specifically the 'Sets: Unordered Collections of Objects' section. In there you will find the following information:

> This performance information assumes
>   adequate implementations for the hash
>   method defined for the objects. With a
>   bad hash function, access and edits
>   take linear time.

and

> The objects in a set must respond to
>   the NSObject protocol methods hash and
>   isEqual: (see NSObject for more
>   information). If mutable objects are
>   stored in a set, either the hash
>   method of the objects shouldn’t depend
>   on the internal state of the mutable
>   objects or the mutable objects
>   shouldn’t be modified while they’re in
>   the set. For example, a mutable
>   dictionary can be put in a set, but
>   you must not change it while it is in
>   there. (Note that it can be difficult
>   to know whether or not a given object
>   is in a collection).

So, yes, [hash](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000052-BBCGFFCH) and [isEqual](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000052-BBCCECDG) are used as you had assumed.

Comment: I should have mentioned that I did read that, as well as the relevant NSSet documentation.  If you really read it though, you'll notice it never says anything about whether "isEqual" is used, only that objects must implement it.  Since you are required to implement isEquals: if you implement hash, that same advice would apply even if all NSSet actually used was hash.  The interesting thing is that they only warn against hash and mutability.  If they used isEqual, one would think the same warning would apply there.

Answer (score 15):

I'd like to step in and give further information about NSSet's use of `hash` and `isEqual:`, since I have encountered weird bugs recently and found that they were due to me overlooking `hash`.

When you store custom objects in a set, NSSet uses the value returned by your `hash` method to group objects in distinct bins, in which they're compared to one another using their respective `isEqual:` method. So basically, `hash` will always be called on your object when inserting, building, testing membership and so on, and if this object falls into a bin where there are *other* objects, its `isEqual` method will be used to distinguish it from them.

That's why `hash` must *always* be the same for objects considered equal, and as much as possible, yield values that will spread objects evenly. The latter property ensures the bins are as small as possible, minimizing calls to `isEqual:`.

Comment: Thanks for saying what the documentation does not say

Comment: What are bins here?